# Prestashop: how to stop CMS editor from redirecting after save

Tags: prestashop

In Prestashop, it is so annoying that after editing and saving a CMS page (in the BO), I am automatically redirected to the CMS main page. If I want to edit again, I have to click on "edit" again and it gets really repetitive.

Is there any way to alter the **admin/tabs/adminCMS.php** so that saving edits does NOT redirect me to the CMS main list page?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you don't use the "Save and stay" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the reply. I'm using **Prestashop 1.4.9**, so I didn't have that functionality. Someone on Prestashop forum let me know the solution:

Go to admin directory/tabs and open AdminCms.php. About line 295 find and delete or comment out

```
Tools::redirectAdmin($currentIndex.'&id_cms_category='.(int)$cms->id_cms_category.'&conf='.(int)($cms->id ? 3 : 4).'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminCMSContent'));
```

and add

```
Tools::redirectAdmin($currentIndex.'&id_cms='.(int)$cms->id.'&updatecms&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminCMSContent'));
```

Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Hello Jay Na? Which version of PrestaShop are you using? In 1.5 there is a feature called "Save and Stay" in which you will not be redirected to the main page.